# How are triangles oriented in a plane?

Tags: geometry, visualization

I was thinking about how the plane in geometry is defined and was wondering, obviously if I draw a triangle, for example, in $2$D I know what it is and looks like as I have defined an orientation between the triangle and me. But how do I think of a triangle in terms of the plane in general? Since in the plane there isn't a defined orientation between the object and me, how can I imagine it?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. What you're saying is, when I do plane geometry, I can look down on the plane from above. That's my perspective. But for a general object, what does the perspective look like?

Comment: @AlfredYerger Yes, I think so. What I am asking is about say for a given triangle how to imagine it in the plane because it isn't defined a certain orientation to me. In the case of the circle, for example, this is no longer an issue.

Comment: Let me ask you a question of my own. I think your answer will help me answer you. Why does the specific orientation matter? Are there situations where one perspective is better than others in your mind?

Comment: @AlfredYerger It's not that it doesn't matter. It's just like how do I even imagine what it looks like in the plane? Obviously, the triangle exists mathematically as a collection of points in space that occupy a certain area, but visually is there a way to interpret it? For an example, say I have the right triangle with sides $3,4,5$. This can be defined in the $2D$ plane as a set that can be rotated or translated anywhere.

Comment: Well you could fix some point in the triangle (or outside it) as the origin, and then represent it geometrically.

Comment: So if I go stare directly down at the triangle $3-4-5$ in the plane, will the hypotenuse be south to me?

Comment: It can if you want it to be! You can orient the triangle however you want. Rotations and translations are a type of mapping of the plane called an "isometry." You can choose any coordinates you want for your shape as long as they are all isometric.

Comment: @AlfredYerger What if I don't define coordinates and just say "the triangle $3-4-5$ in the plane"? All I am saying is that visually talking about a triangle in a plane doesn't seem possible as there is no direction specified or orientation to you.

Comment: The plane is homogeneous. Any pair of orthogonal lines can be used to make coordinates. In fact, if you know linear algebra, any two different lines can be used to make coordinates... so you can specify any direction you want. It is truly arbitrary.

Comment: @AlfredYerger So if I decide to not have any orientation to me would it be impossible to visualize?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Ask yourself how it would make sense to say "_the_ triangle $3,4,5$ in the plane", since as soon as we put any $3,4,5$ triangle in a plane we can make many copies of it, so how can any one of them be "the" $3,4,5$ triangle? I think I would rather say "_a_ $3,4,5$ triangle", meaning that it certainly has a location and orientation, but unless I am more specific about which triangle, I will only say things about it that are true no matter what that position and orientation are.